# SQL: Count column and show the total result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sum

This is my current select on my table:

```
SELECT count(*) as Titel, KuenstlerName FROM Bild GROUP BY KuenstlerName;
+-------+---------------+
| Titel | KuenstlerName |
+-------+---------------+
|     3 | Klee          |
|     1 | Klingt        |
|     1 | Marc          |
|     6 | Picasso       |
|     1 | van Gogh      |
+-------+---------------+
```

Is there a way to add a new row/column or just display a message which returns the total values of the column 'Titel'.

**For Example:**

```
+-------+---------------+
| Titel | KuenstlerName |
+-------+---------------+
|     3 | Klee          |
|     1 | Klingt        |
|     1 | Marc          |
|     6 | Picasso       |
|     1 | van Gogh      |
|    12 | Total         |
+-------+---------------+

+-------+---------------+-----+
| Titel | KuenstlerName |Total|
+-------+---------------+-----+
|     3 | Klee          |  12 |
|     1 | Klingt        |     |
|     1 | Marc          |     |
|     6 | Picasso       |     |
|     1 | van Gogh      |     |
+-------+---------------+-----+
```

**or:**

```
+-------+---------------+
| Titel | KuenstlerName |
+-------+---------------+
|     3 | Klee          |
|     1 | Klingt        |
|     1 | Marc          |
|     6 | Picasso       |
|     1 | van Gogh      |
+-------+---------------+
Total: 12
```

*Thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but this would work:

```
SELECT count(*) as Titel, KuenstlerName 
FROM Bild 
GROUP BY KuenstlerName
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) as Titel, 'Total' AS KuenstlerName 
FROM Bild
```

(someone jumped in with virtually the same solution while I was typing, UNION ALL should be marginally faster than UNION alone though).

Comment: There is difference between `count` and `sum`. OP seems expecting `sum` but not `count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as Titel, KuenstlerName FROM Bild GROUP BY KuenstlerName
UNION 
SELECT count(*),'Total' FROM Bild
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT KuenstlerName, count(*) as Titel FROM Bild GROUP BY KuenstlerName
UNION 
SELECT "Total:" AS KuenstlerName, count(*) AS Titel FROM Bild
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT sum(titel),coalesce(KuenstlerName,'Total') 
  FROM testdb.titel 
 GROUP BY KuenstlerName with rollup;`

Thanks.

Added screenshot of result.

[image]

Comment: It adds the 'Total' row but all the sums are 0

Comment: @BlueFox weird. It works perfectly on my query. I added screenshot for your reference. Thanks.